# Equation of cone

Tags: geometry, 3d

The plane $lx+my+nz=0$ moves in such a way that its intersection with the planes 
$$ax+by+cz+d=0$$
$$a'x+b'y+c'z+d'=0$$
are perpendicular. Show that the normal to the plane through the origin describes in general a cone of second degree and find its equation?

Comment: Welcome to MSE: It will be more likely that you get an answer if you show us that you made some effort.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the plane $\pi_0 \;:\, lx+my+nz=0$ "moves" means of course that
the parameters $l,m,n$ vary.

The intersection between two planes is a line normal to both the normals to the planes.

Hence
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf t}_{\,1}  = \left( {l,m,n} \right) \times \left( {a,b,c} \right) = \left( {cm - bn, - cl + an,bl - am} \right)  \cr 
  & {\bf t}_{\,2}  = \left( {l,m,n} \right) \times \left( {a',b',c'} \right) = \left( {c'm - b'n, - c'l + a'n,b'l - a'm} \right) \cr} 
$$
and we shall impose that the two lines remain normal to each other, i.e.
$$
{\bf t}_{\,1}  \cdot {\bf t}_{\,2}  = 0 = \left( {cm - bn} \right)\left( {c'm - b'n} \right) + \left( { - cl + an} \right)\left( { - c'l + a'n} \right) + \left( {bl - am} \right)\left( {b'l - a'm} \right)
$$

Expand that to get a quadratic equation in $l,m,n$. I think you can proceed by yourself now.